# Opening YouTube channel from an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, youtube

How to open my YouTube channel on YouTube application from my own application?

I did ask about Instagram and Facebook and they are have in API Documentation info about it, but in the YouTube docs I couldn't found anything about it.

**I did try:**

```
var url = NSURL(string: "youtube://channel/channel_id")
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!)
{  
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

But it doesn't open my youtube channel. Cannot find my url. Do anyone knows how to achieve my YouTube channel by YouTube app from my own application?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]];

Answer (score 4):

> Update for Swift 3 and iOS 10+

OK, there are two easy steps to achieve this:

First, you have to modify `Info.plist` to list `Youtube` with `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. Simply open `Info.plist` as a Source Code, and paste this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>youtube</string>
</array>
```

After that, you can open any youtube URL inside Youtube application by simply substituting `https://` with `youtube://`. Here is a complete code, you can link this code to any button you have as an Action:

```
@IBAction func YoutubeAction() {

    let YoutubeUser =  "Your Username"
    let appURL = NSURL(string: "youtube://www.youtube.com/user/\(YoutubeUser)")!
    let webURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/user/\(YoutubeUser)")!
    let application = UIApplication.shared

    if application.canOpenURL(appURL as URL) {
        application.open(appURL as URL)
    } else {
        // if Youtube app is not installed, open URL inside Safari
        application.open(webURL as URL)
    }

}
```